# Proof that if f(g) is one-to-one, then g is one-to-one

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have seen other questions and answers regarding this proof, but I am having trouble with the overall logic in it. Here is how the proof seems to look:

$\;$
$$\;\;\text{Suppose that g is not one-to-one. Then we can find distinct}\;x_1,x_2 \in X \; \text{for which}\; \:\:\:\:\:\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; g(x_1)=g(x_2)=y. \;\text{But then }f \circ g(x_1)=f(y)=f \circ g(x_2) \;\text{so} \; f \circ g \;\text{is also not one-to-one. Therefore,}\;f\circ g \;\text{is not one-to-one unless g is also one-to-one. } $$

$\;$

Here is my reasoning which goes differently than this:

$\;$

$\;$
$\;\;\text{Suppose that g is not one-to-one. Then we can find distinct}\;x_1,x_2 \in X \; \text{for which}\; \:\:\:\:\:\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; g(x_1)=g(x_2)=y. \;\text{Then it could be the case that we have} \; f \circ g(x_1),\;f \circ g(x_2), \; \text{where}\; g(x_1) =g(x_2)=y, \text{and therefore }f \circ g(x_1)=f \circ g(x_2)=f \circ g(y). \text{Since the outputs of}\;f \circ g(x_1),\;f \circ g(x_2) \;\text{are only equal when }g(x_1)=g(x_2), f \circ g  \;\text{is one-to-one. But in this case, g does not need to be one-to-one in order for this to be true. }  $

$\;$

If someone would be able to explain the error in my reasoning I would appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: I can't follow your argument.  If $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$ then $f\circ g(x_1)=f\circ g(x_2)$.  Is that all you are saying?

Comment: You wrongly write $\cdots=f\circ g(x_2)=f\circ g(y)$. It should be $\cdots=f\circ g(x_2)=f(y)$.

Comment: This is MUCH easier to do without contradiction.  The direct proof is simpler and shows why it should be true to begin with

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your reasoning is the following:

In the beginning you assume that $g(x_1) = g(x_2) = y$. Later you say that $f(g(x_1))$ is only equal to $f(g(x_2))$ if $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$. But you assumed that  $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$ and thus it must be the case that $f(g(x_1)) = f(g(x_2))$. So f composed with g is not one-to-one if you assume that $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$.

This is an indirect proof of the lemma, meaning that you prove that if $g$ is not one-to-one, then $f \circ g$ is not one to one. This is equivalent to saying that if $f \circ g$ is one-to-one, then $g$ must be one-to-one.

Comment: I am slightly confused when you say f composed with g is not one-to-one if you assume $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$. Wouldn't this then mean f composed with g is one-to-one?

Comment: Well you have to think about the concept of the indirect proof I think: What you want to show is: if $f \circ g$ one-to-one, then $g$ one-to-one. In order to show this, you formulate the equivalent statement: if $g$ not one-to-one, then $f \circ g$ not one-to-one. So now you proof this second statement. To do that, you assume that $g$ is not one-to-one (So $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$ for some $x_1, x_2$) and then derive that $f \circ g$ cannot be one-to-one.

Comment: So I would have the statements "If g is not one-to-one, then $f \circ g$ is not one to one." Since g is not one-to-one, it is the case that $g(x_1)=g(x_2),$and $x_1$ is not equal to $x_2$. We want to show that this implies $f \circ g$ is not one-to-one. If $f \circ g$ is not one-to-one, then it must be the case that there is $f(g(x_1))=f(g(x_2)$ such that $g(x_1)$ is not equal to $g(x_2)$. Can't $f \circ g$ still be one-to-one though in this case?

Comment: For instance, why can't we use $g=x^2$ and $f=x$. If $x_1=2$ and $x_2=-2$, then g maps them both to 4 (not one-to-one). But then isn't $f(g)$ one-to-one, since it would simply map each $g(x)$ from $[0,\infin)$ to $[0,\inf)$?

Comment: Almost: you made one small mistake in your last step. You wrote that $f \circ g$ is not one-to-one if $f(g(x_1)) = f(g(x_2))$ such that $g(x_1)$ is not equal to $g(x_2)$. This is wrong. The argument to the function $f \circ g$ is $x$ and not $g(x)$. So $f \circ g$ is not one-to-one if $f(g(x_1)) = f(g(x_2))$ such that $x_1$ is not equal to $x_2$.

Comment: I think what you are struggling with is the concept of function composition. If you write that $g(x) = x^2$ and $f(x) = x$ then the function $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x)) = f(x^2) = f(y) = y = x^2$. I tried to clarify by substitution $y = x^2$.

Comment: Why would the argument to the function not be the domain? Isn't the domain g(x)?

Comment: When you write $f \circ g$, you are talking about a completely new function built out of two function f and g. This new function maps from domain X to Range Y. So the argument to the function $f \circ g$ must come from X. The value y of the function $f \circ g$ for the argument x is computed like this $f(g(x)) = y$.

Comment: That helped clarify it for me. Thank you so much!